# Is my understanding of differential forms integration correct?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, surface-integrals

I'm trying to understand the definition of the integral of a general $k$-form $\omega$ over a parameterised $k$-manifold $M$ :$$\intop_{M}\omega=\intop_{D}\omega\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u_{1}},\ldots,\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u_{k}}\right)du_{1}\cdots du_{k},$$

where $D$ is a region of $u_{1},\ldots,u_{k}$ space. So I'm looking at the 2-form version of this integral for a parameterised surface $S$:$$\intop_{S}\omega=\intop_{D}\omega\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial v}\right)du\,dv.$$

I've come up with an intuitive “explanation” for this second integral (which also works for higher dimensions) that, at my elementary level appears convincing, but I may be wrong.

So my question is, is the following argument correct/valid?

First, I note that a 2-form $\omega=dx\wedge dy$ acting on two tangent vectors to $S$ is given by$$\left(dx\wedge dy\right)\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial v}\right)=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{array}\right|.$$

Then, from the change of variable formula, I see that$$dx\wedge dy=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{array}\right|\,du\wedge dv.$$

By substitution I then say$$\omega=\omega\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial v}\right)\,du\wedge dv.$$And integrate this to get the original integral.

$$\intop_{S}\omega=\intop_{D}\omega\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial u},\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial v}\right)du\,dv.$$

This is my attempt to improve a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325004/integrating-2-form-and-change-of-variables-question), which has not been well received.

Comment: Do you know what an exterior derivative is?

Comment: A basic, understanding, yes. Schulz and Schulz in "A Practical Introduction to Differential Forms" give four rules for using the $d$ operator, which I could follow. I also understand their derivation of the change of variables formula, which involved multiplying out $dx\wedge dy$ to give the equation I state in my question.

Comment: Do you know what the "Generalized Stokes Theorem" is?

Comment: Vaguely, but aren't you drifting away from the point of my question? I just want to know if the argument I give is correct. Thanks.

Comment: In your reasoning, you chose a specific 2-form. How can you use this singular case to "prove" the formula for the integration of a 2-form over a 2-manifold? I bring up the Stokes Theorem because all of these definitions on the integration of k-forms are based on the intuition behind the Stokes Theorem.

Comment: This is fine, and — without going back to check — looks *just* like your original question. By the way, you might find some of [my lectures on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) helpful, particularly the lectures on differential forms, pullbacks, integrals, and examples with line integrals, surface integrals, and higher dimensions.

Comment: @Peter4075 This link may be useful:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317540/intuition-behind-generalized-stokes-theorem

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. My motivation for both questions was an intriguing quote I recently came across: “A change of parameterization of a curve is really just a change of variables. The whole point of differential forms is that integration of forms is designed to work consistently with the change of variables formula. Or another way to think of it, is that the change of variables formula is baked into the definition of differential forms." My argument seemed (to me) to explain that “baked into” notion, so I wanted to check it out.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. The change of variables theorem says precisely that integration of differential forms is precisely what makes sense: If we pull back by an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, the integral doesn't change. ($\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_A^B f(g(t))g'(t)\,dt$ ($g(A)=a$, $g(B)=b$) is the simplest case. (See lecture 29 and following.)